Introduction to Analytic Number Theory Tom M. Apostol Exercice 8.2
Problem Statement
Let ((x)) be defined as:
\begin{cases} 
x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } x \text{ is not an integer}, \\
0, & \text{if } x \text{ is an integer}.
\end{cases}
We need to prove that for integers k and n  with (n>0), the following equality holds:
$$
\left( \left( \frac{k}{n} \right) \right) = -\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \cot\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right) \sin\left( \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right)
$$
I tried the following steps but i am pretty stucked...
Step-by-Step Process:

Start with the sum:

$$
\left( \frac{k}{n} \right) = -\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \cot\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right) \sin\left( \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right)
$$

Rewrite the cotangent term using the identity $$\cot(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} $$:

$$
\left( \frac{k}{n} \right) = -\frac{1}{2n} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{\cos\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right)}{\sin\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right)} \sin\left( \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right)
$$

Apply the sum-to-product identity for sine and cosine:

$$
\sin(A)\cos(B) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\sin(A + B) + \sin(A - B)\right]
$$
We can rewrite $$ \sin\left( \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right) $$ as:
$$
\sin\left( \frac{2\pi k m}{n} \right) \cos\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sin\left( \frac{(2k+1)\pi m}{n} \right) + \sin\left( \frac{(2k-1)\pi m}{n} \right) \right]
$$

Substitute this into the sum:

$$
\left( \frac{k}{n} \right) = -\frac{1}{4n} \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sin\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right)} \left[ \sin\left( \frac{(2k+1)\pi m}{n} \right) + \sin\left( \frac{(2k-1)\pi m}{n} \right) \right]
$$

Split the sum into two parts:

$$
\left( \frac{k}{n} \right) = -\frac{1}{4n} \left[ \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{\sin\left( \frac{(2k+1)\pi m}{n} \right)}{\sin\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right)} + \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{\sin\left( \frac{(2k-1)\pi m}{n} \right)}{\sin\left( \frac{\pi m}{n} \right)} \right]
$$

Here i tried to split the sum in two separate sums and using Euler's identity for sine and cosine to evaluate each sum to a close form expressed by k and n but it doesnt seem to work...

Any help appreciated.

What happened when you set $~k = 6, ~n \in {2,3,4,5},~$ pulled out a piece of scratch paper, and checked the computations?  Was the hypothesis accurate in all $~4~$ cases?  Did you find a pattern in the data that suggested an intermediate hypothesis?  If so, what intermediate hypothesis?  What steps did you take to try to prove the intermediate hypothesis?

Re my last comment, I know virtually nothing about your posted math problem, and I have no idea whether the strategy that I suggested in my first comment would be helpful in any way.  However, such a strategy is simply a very basic first step.  That is, in general for such problems, it is sometimes helpful if you try to expand your intuition to obtain a deeper understanding about what is going on.

Thank you but the approach to this problem is by proving perhaps a related lemma first or rather continue my reasoning further...

Your immediately analytical approach is a reasonable first try.  However, when such a try fails to conquer the problem, for this type of problem, a reasonably constructive approach is to follow the strategy that I have suggested.  Time and time again, the elbow-grease approach has given me helpful insights that initially eluded me.  Since your iniitial analytical approach did not conquer the problem, I allege that it is time to examine specific illustrative cases, to (perhaps) aid your visualization of the problem.
